# How to enable ip address for all ports in the Cisco IOS Web Browser

Tags: cisco, ethernet, network

Good afternoon, how do i enable the ip address in webui for the cisco switch you can see the picture below ipv4 is unassigned, everything looks good with me.

[image]

Comment: GigabitEthernet0/0 is not a switch interface, it is a management interface, and it is not connected. It is for out-of-band switch management. Typically, you create an SVI in one of the VLANs and assign an IP address on it to manage the switch. You will also need to assign the default gateway if it is used as a layer-2 switch.

Comment: The other switch interfaces default to layer-2 interfaces for which you do not assign IP addresses. If the interface is for a layer-3 link, the you can use the CLI and set the interface to `no switchport` the configure an IP address, but you do not do that for layer-2 access interfaces.

Comment: You are right sir, i was checking other stacks also, and GigabitEthernet0/0 is not a switch interface, I have to bring this to our management before creating an SVI in one of the VLANs and assigning an IP address on it to manage the switch

Comment: No. The management interface is for out of band management. You can manage the switch from a layer-3 SVI.